# other keyboard view only loads after killing the app

Tags: java, android, keyboard, sharedpreferences

I'm playing around with Softkeyboard

i made a checkbox in my preferences

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="OneColors"
        android:summary="Show one color keys above the keyboard"
        android:title="One color keys" >
```

After that i made a qwertycolor.xml with more buttons

then i replaced

```
this.mQwertyKeyboard = new EmojiKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
```

@ `onInitializeInterface()` with

```
    SharedPreferences lala = 
            getSharedPreferences("com.keyboard_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (lala.getBoolean("OneColors", true)){
        this.mQwertyKeyboard = new EmojiKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwertycolor);
    } else {
        this.mQwertyKeyboard = new EmojiKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    }
```

the problem i have got now is that my keyboard changes but only after killing the whole app and opening it again

Comment: When are you expecting the keyboard to change, and what are you doing to trigger it?  If all you have is this here, you'd only see a change at startup or around major configuration changes.  If you want to be able to see it after every settings change, you need to switch out on something more frequently called, probably onStartInput or onStartInputView.

Comment: @GabeSechan will try this thnx

Comment: @GabeSechan yeah it worked thnx added it to onStartInput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by moving

```
        SharedPreferences lala = 
            getSharedPreferences("eu.drgekko.rftoolz_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (lala.getBoolean("OneColors", true)){
        this.mQwertyKeyboard = new EmojiKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwertycolor);

    } else {
        this.mQwertyKeyboard = new EmojiKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);

    }
```

to `onStartInput()`

thnx to
@GabeSechan